# CSS image is not fitting into container

Tags: css

There are seven images of different size and I want to put all the images below the big image. Can any one please help me to solve this?

```css
.imagelist img{
  width: 100px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  font-size: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="images/wide.jpg" width="100%" alt="wide-image">
</div>
<div class="imagelist">
  <img src="images/a.jpg" width="100px;">
  <img src="images/b.jpg" width="100px;">
  <img src="images/c.jpg" width="100px;">
  <img src="images/d.jpg" width="100px; height:90px;">
  <img src="images/e.jpg" width="100px;">
  <img src="images/f.jpg" width="100px;">
  <img src="images/g.jpg" width="100px;">
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: This site is for programming questions. You show some code, explain how it's not working, and we (maybe) try help fix it. We are not here to look at pictures of problems, or write code for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following solution:

```css
.imagelist img {
  float:left;
  width:calc(100% / 7 - 4px);
  border:2px solid black;
  font-size:0;
}
.imagelist {
  clear:both;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x350" width="100%" alt="wide-image">
</div>
<div class="imagelist">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x350">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x350">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x350">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x350">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x350">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x350">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x350">
</div>
```